# Display Vector Graphics in Android 4.x below

Tags: android, image, vector

My app has a problem displaying vector graphics in Android 4.4.4 below (API v19). All graphics will mess up every time it shows on device's screen. It gets worse with locking the device and unlocking again with the app in the foreground.
There is no problem in Android 5.x or later.

I am writing a native app using Android's java.
My vector graphics format is SVG.
I am using API v27, and support library v11.
I tested it on multiple devices including phone and tablets!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was due to the Lottie 2.3.1 library I used. I downgraded to Lottie 2.0.0 its fixed!
The problem lies in dependency between support library other libraries.